# eBay API: How do I specify "Standard Shipping (FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery®)" as a shipping service?

Tags: c#, .net, ebay-api

I am wondering how I specify "Standard Shipping (FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery®)" as a shipping service using the eBay API. Can anyone provide any pointers? All of the samples just use the "Standard Shipping" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify **FedExHomeDelivery**. A table of shipping services for most eBay sites can be found [here](http://faq.frooition.com/article/what-listing-information-can-i-import-and-export-185.html#ebay-site-details). Simply use the values in the *ID for importing* column for your eBay API calls.

As the types of shipping services change over time you may wish to periodically retrieve the latest services via the API as follows.

- For each eBay site that you are interested in make a call to *[GeteBayDetails](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GeteBayDetails.html)* with a *DetailName* value of *ShippingServiceDetails*.
- In the results iterate over all the *ShippingServiceDetails* elements. Each one is a shipping service for the site that you specified.
- Important properties for each service that you will need to check are,

  - *ValidForSellingFlow* - If this set to *'true'* the service can be used in the Add/Revise/Relist API calls otherwise you can not use it.
  - *Description* - You can use this value when presenting services to a user. The text should match what users see when listing via eBay.
  - *ShippingService* - This is the value that you want to use in your API calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all available shipping methods [in the documentation of `ShippingServiceCodeType`](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/ShippingServiceCodeType.html).

Beware to use the correct ones of the site id where item will be placed.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see one for: Standard Shipping (FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery®)

Comment: Are you sure this method does exist on ebay?

Comment: In the list there are many fedex national and international services. Among them i found: `FedExGround`. Is that what you look for?

Comment: Take a look at the Shipping tab for this item: http://www.ebay.com/itm/270780872824?ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1555.l2649#payId. It is: "Standard Shipping (FedEx Ground or FedEx Home Delivery®)"

Comment: This item is listed on ebay us, are you going to place your item on ebay us? Otherwise i think you eill not be able to use such a method

Comment: Yes, I'll be posting to the US site.